# Sitecore Controller Rendering not found?

Tags: controller, sitecore, rendering

we have a project on sitecore 9 update 2 and everything worked properly, until we had to add a project to the visual studio solution.
I add the project, create the controllers, insert the dlls and create the rendering controllers on sitecore, but they are not displayed, although they are declared with 
namespace.controller.controllerName, namespace.
So I checked the old rendering controllers of the other project and noticed that they are declared with only the controller name without the controller suffix and without the namespace.
Does anyone know how to set this feature on the project?
Regards.

Comment: mmm, any errors?

Comment: Have you some code, maybe the routeConfig.cs

Comment: Any errors in the log of why it can't render your controller.

Comment: I didn't have any error in the logs, the only thing I found was inside the routeconfig a specification for the namespace;
namespaces: new [] {"namespacenam.Controllers"}
I tried to add the new namespace of the project, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything, Sitecore is using normal MVC controller DI to resolve the controller and action by the controller name.